# LIKE on DECIMAL fields

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, .net-3.5, sql-like

I have a search section which would let the users to see orders based on values entered in the Search Box. If the searching value is not entered (for e.g., dates, customer name, sales price etc), top 10 records with OrderDate DESC will be shown. Table with required columns are below.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
(
    OrderId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderPrice NUMERIC(18, 2),
    OrderDate DATETIME  
)

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails
SELECT 100.18 OrderPrice, GETDATE() OrderDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 300.62 OrderPrice, GETDATE() OrderDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 9300.12 OrderPrice, GETDATE() OrderDate
```

Whenever the user enters SalesPrice, I would like to run a query like below in VB.Net from EntityFramework. **Note that SalesPrice is DECIMAL field**.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetails WHERE OrderPrice LIKE '%9300%'
```

I am using System.Data.Entity.dll **version 3.5.0.0**. I started writing it as below:

```
Dim query = From o In e.OrderDetails Select o
If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPrice)) Then
   query = query.Where(Function(i) i.SalesPrice.ToString().Contains(sPrice))
End If
```

Please note that the SalesPrice is a DECIMAL field and I could not use Contains. Hence I had to use a ToString(). But I get the below error.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Any helps are appreciated....

Comment: What is the meaning of searching in decimal field using `LIKE`.Suppose you have 129300 and 19300 in your values. How this prices correlates?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Even if I need to use StartsWith or EndsWith, I still need to convert the decimal value to ToString().

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR: Please revert back the suggested Edits. I do not have enough permissions to reject your edit. This question is specifically a Entity Framework question. The queries are kept just to give more details.....

Comment: @SharminJose Meta-tags shouldn't be included in the title. You clearly tagged entity-framework for your question, that is what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

ToString is not known by L2E, you have to use `SqlFunctions` static methods to do the conversion.

I'm not sure if my VB syntax is ok, but that will work.

```
query = query.Where(Function(i) SqlFunctions.StringConvert(CType(i.SalesPrice, System.Nullable(Of Decimal)).Contains(sPrice))
```

The C# Syntax is:

```
query = query.Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?) x.SalesPrice).Contains(sPrice));
```

Comment: Are you sure it would work on the EF 3.5? I had seen it in some other examples, but could not find any where telling it can be used in 3.5.

Comment: `SqlFunctions` is not available in .Net 3.5, starting in 4.0

Comment: I just edited the Question (added it in the heading also) to highlight the version I use. I had already mentioned in the Question, but did not highlight it. Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score -1):

You  might be able to do something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetails WHERE CAST(OrderPrice, VarChar(10)) LIKE '%9300%'
```

This would be very inefficient on the server side if you didn't have other checks in the WHERE clause to prevent a full table scan.

I don't speak LINQ so your on your own there.

Comment: The question is on how to apply LIKE operator over Decimal fields on EF 3.5. I had actually added that information in the Question's Text itself. But someone changed it to LIKE on DECIMAL fields.

Comment: No problem. I was just replying to the second set of code and pointing out that you can use such a construct for doing string ops on numbers.